# Code in a test app that interacts with a View of the AUT must run in the main apps thread but is .runOnUiThread always needed?

Tags: android, unit-testing

While  reading the  testing tutorial at  http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/testing/activity_test.html

I  began to  wonder  why   is  the  below code  needed.

```
public void testSpinnerUI() {

    mActivity.runOnUiThread(
      new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          mSpinner.requestFocus();
          mSpinner.setSelection(INITIAL_POSITION);
        } // end of run() method definition
      } // end of anonymous Runnable object instantiation
    ); // end of invocation of runOnUiThread
```

Why is it not better to use    sendKeys( KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN );  alone  to  set  the  focus?

Such  as  here

http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.com/2010/01/unit-and-functional-testing-in-android.html

```
public void testAdd() throws Throwable {

        //First field value
        sendKeys( KeyEvent.KEYCODE_3 );
        sendKeys( KeyEvent.KEYCODE_PERIOD );
        sendKeys( KeyEvent.KEYCODE_5 );
```